# Mysqli query UPDATE WHERE

Tags: php, mysql

Table details :

**start decimal(10,2),**

**finish    decimal(10,2),**

**total = finish-start.**

I want to update every total row in the database where the start time is smaller than the finish time to null.
Below is the query I'm using .

```
$query ="UPDATE $user_table_hours set total='' ,cash='' WHERE finish < start";
if(!$result){echo printf("Errormessage: %s\n", mysqli_error($mysqli_connect));}
```

it doesn't give me any errors when i run it . but it doesn't update the row.

Comment: Might be a stupid question, but is the query actually being run? $result = $mysqli_connect->query($query);

Comment: Yes the query is being run , i would be a complete idiot if i wouldn't run it.

Comment: Not necessarily, everyone makes stupid mistakes once in a while.

Comment: Can you post your complete code? Where's $result being set?
Have you tried intentionally putting in a wrong query in order to test if your error handling is working correctly?

Comment: $query ="UPDATE $user_table_ore SET total='',cash='' WHERE start<finish";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli_connect ,$query);
if(!$result){echo printf("Errormessage: %s\n", mysqli_error($mysqli_connect));}

Comment: And if i change one of the fields it gives me this : Errormessage: Unknown column 'startx' in 'where clause' 56

Comment: If total is also a decimal why are you setting it to an empty string instead of NULL?

Comment: I tried using NULL but it still doesn't update the rows.

Comment: Moved things around and got the query to work .

Comment: Moved things around and got the query to work , not sure why it didn't work before.   
$query ="UPDATE $user_table_ore set `total`=NULL,`cash`=NULL WHERE `start` >= `finish`";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli_connect ,$query);
if(!$result){echo printf("Errormessage: %s\n", mysqli_error($mysqli_connect));}

Answer (score 0):

You cant able to compare a decimal value with null field.NULL field can be compare only with ISNULL in MySQL.

[NULL comparisons in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html)

Can you set a default integer value in start and finish. After setting a default value on your table update the field with default value for existing NULL entries.And then run your query. It will work